# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded - simple program

Tags: python

I was trying to test the `property()` function in Python for a `Test` class, I have created simple fget, fset, fdel equivalent methods. When I ran a simple test, I am faced with `RecursionError`, there are multiple such scenarios on SO, but none of them is as simple and straightforward as mine, can someone help me in understand the problem here ? I am using `Python 3.7`.

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = 100

    def getvalue(self):
        return self.value

    def setvalue(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def deletevalue(self):
        del self.value

    value = property(getvalue, setvalue, deletevalue)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    t = Test(10)
    print(t.value)
    t.value = 200
    print(t.value)
    del t.value
    print(t.value)
```

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
   `File "/Users//PycharmProjects/Test/Helloworld/T2.py", line 20, in 
      <module>
    t = Test(10)
       File "/Users//PycharmProjects/Test/Helloworld/T2.py", line 4, in 
     __init__
      self.value = 100
      File "/Users//PycharmProjects/Test/Helloworld/T2.py", line 10, in 
      setvalue
      self.value = value
      File "/Users//PycharmProjects/Test/Helloworld/T2.py", line 10, in 
      setvalue
       self.value = value
      File "/Users//PycharmProjects/Test/Helloworld/T2.py", line 10, in 
     setvalue
      self.value = value
     [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
         RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I disagree; a property is *meant* to be a class variable. See also the [official CPython example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: You have a good answer to your question. Also note that for this type of use case the more idiomatic implementation uses the `@property` decorator. For example: https://stackabuse.com/the-python-property-decorator/

Comment: @FMc Indeed, using the decorator would definitely be the more orthodox approach. If you don't mind, I'll edit my answer to include that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that you have named your *instance variable* and your *class variable* (which is the `property`) the same thing: `value`.

Accordingly, when you call `__init__`, it tries to call `setvalue`, which calls itself, and so on...

The variable underlying properties should be named differently (the [official example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) uses a preceding underscore):

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = 100

    def getvalue(self):
        return self._value

    def setvalue(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def deletevalue(self):
        del self._value

    value = property(getvalue, setvalue, deletevalue)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    t = Test(10)
    print(t.value)
    t.value = 200
    print(t.value)
    del t.value
    print(t.value)
```

This gives the expected result:

```
100
200
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute '_value'
```